# Sql retrive orders woocommerce - error in statement

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

SQL:

```
select  
max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'id_order' THEN pm.meta_value END ) as 'ID_Order',
max( CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_qty' THEN oim.meta_value END ) as 'qty'
   
   
from
    wp_posts p 
    join wp_postmeta pm on p.ID = pm.post_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_items oi on p.ID = oi.order_id
    join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim on oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
where
    post_type = 'shop_order' 
    and p.id = 107291
    and (select oim.meta_value where oim.meta_key = '_tax_class')   = 'no_tax'

        
        group by p.id;
```

Result:

ID_Order qty
107291   **NULL**

If i comment section:
**and (select oim.meta_value where oim.meta_key = '_tax_class')   = 'no_tax'** result is proper.

ID_Order qty
107291   **1**

How to make good where condition base on meta value and meta key?

Comment: Subquery may return a rowset which cannot be compared with scalar value. Subquery refers to external columns which is "in current row" selection due to FROM absence.

Comment: Ok, undestand. But how avoid subquery and still use where statement?

Comment: You need to check one row in a group. Hence you must apply aggregate function in HAVING.

Comment: group by p.id,oim.meta_key,oim.meta_value
    HAVING oim.meta_key = '_tax_class' and oim.meta_value = 'no_tax';

And still NULL values

Comment: Hi, anybody can help me with that statement?